# What is the meaning behind the Episode names for the original season, Träumend and Ouvertüre?

Tags: rozen-maiden

In original season, *Träumend* (season 2) and *Ouvertüre* (prequel OVA) each episode has a strange name such as *Fräulein Rose* (Season 1 Episode 1), *Rozenkristall* (Season 2 Episode 1) and *Ewigkeit* (OVA Episode 1). About the only ones I understand are from Season 2:

- Episode 2 *Enju* which is when I think Enju is introduced
- Episode 12 *Alice*

  > being the final battles to determine Alice

I am wondering what is the meaning behind these names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen the OVA and do not have acess to any of the episodes. So I can't really help connect the meaning of the titles to theyr episodes.

Those names are in german, and perhaps not very good german.

*Fräulein Rose* being composed of *Fräulein*, which is an outdated word for a young or unmarried woman (Wikitionary says the word in now avoided and considered disrespectful and sexist) and the word *Rose*, which does means rose, meaning something like "Young Lady Rose" or "Young lady of the Rose". Probably meaning Shinku.

*Rozenkristall* is a result of the word *Rose* being turned into an adjective for *kristall*, which means "crystal".
The word would mean "Crystal Rose". Which is the meaning of "Barasuishou".

*Ewigkeit* means *Eternity*.

*Träumend* means *Dreaming*.

*Ouvertüre* is *Overture*, no secrets, as the OVAs are a prequel.

I suggest using google translator for any other german title you find in the series, as it seems to be the theme used by the producers.

Comment: That's "Rose Crystal", not other way around in both Japanese and German.

Answer (score 3):

Well, none of the names are truely *strange,* they are merely German ;) Going by the episode lists on [AniDB](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=2386) which I remembered to be consistent with the titles I saw on-screen the titles and translations are:

- *Fräulein Rose* — *Miss Rose* or *Lady of the Rose;* likely a reference to Shinku. Her appearance.
- *Kleine Beere* — *Small berry,* Hina-ichigo’s translated name as far as I remember. Her appearance.
- *Mercury Lampe* — This is nonsense in German. A *mercury lamp* (also [Suigintou’s translated name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26829/13532)) would be *Quecksilberdampflampe.* But that is long and doesn’t sound poetic, (as nothing containing *Quecksilber* does) so they probably decided to just translate *lamp* to *Lampe.* The reference is, of course, Suigintou’s appearance.
- *Jade Stern* (should be *Jadestern* in proper German) — *Jade star.* Suiseiseki’s translated name and the episode in which she appears.
- *Die Treppe* — *The stairs.* You remember that horrific filler episode, don’t you?
- *Tränen* — *Tears.* Contrary to the earlier episodes I don’t quite know what this refers to.
- *Träume* — *Dreams.* Because of the dream Shinku is in.
- *Lapislazuli Stern* (should be *Lapislazulistern* in proper German) — *Lapis lazuli star.* Souseiseki’s translated name and the episode in which she appears.
- *Die Gefängnis* — *The prison.* They got the article wrong, it should be *das.* I don’t know why none of the production crew could look the word up in a dictionary when they did so well with everything else (even umlauts). But whatever. The title of course references the prison the dolls and Jun are in in Souseiseki’s master’s dream.
- *Abschied* — *Farewell,* preparing for Shinku’s departure into the N-field.
- *Schicksal* — *Fate.* Because of all the fate that is involved.
- *Reiner Rubin* — *Pure ruby.* Shinku’s translated name.

  > Because it is all about Shinku, repairing her and her intermediate win against Suigintou.

[Rozen Maiden Träumend](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=3169): (*träumend* is *dreaming*)

- *Rozenkristall* (should be *Rosenkristall*) — *Rose Crystal.* As was said, this is Bara-Suishou and her appearance episode.
- *Enju* — Erm, yeah, it’s a proper noun. We get to know him.
- *Kanarienvogel* — *Canary.* This is the episode where we get to know the canary yellow doll Kanaria.
- *Vereinbarung* — *Contract.*

  > Because Suiseiseki enters one with Jun.
- *Der Brief* — *The letter,* because both Hina-Ichigo and Suiseiseki copy Souseiseki in writing letters of thanks and the episode centres around this.
- *Engel* — *Angel.* This is the episode where Suigintou meets Megu.
- *Teegesellschaft* — *Tea company* (could be both the people around you and the firm — like in English). Kanaria manages to ‘persuade’ the other dolls to join her master for a tea party.
- *Puppenmacher* — *Doll maker.* This is where Jun starts visiting Enju to watch how dolls are made.
- *Der Tadel* — *The reproach.*

  > There’s quite a lot of criticism going on from one side to another — it’s practically the first Alice game episode. I’ll let you choose who is being reproached.
- *Tomoe* — well, okay ;).

  > The one where Hina-Ichigo gets to be with Tomoe one last time.
- *Rosengarten* — *Rose garden.*

  > A reference to the dolls’ fighting grounds.
- *Alice* — yeah, you got that.

[Rozen Maiden Ouvertüre](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=4772): (*Ouvertüre* is *overture*)

- *Ewigkeit* — *Eternity.* I don’t quite know why this name was chosen, but maybe just because it sounds cool.
- *Eitelkeit* — *Vanity.* Possibly because this episode shows us the source of Suigintou’s pride in herself.