# Why is Suigintou's title "Mercury Lamp?"

Tags: rozen-maiden

Looking on the [Rozen Maiden Wikia](http://rozenmaiden.wikia.com/) for the Rozen Maidens, I notice they all have titles

- Suigintou = Mercury Lamp
- Shinku = Pure Ruby
- Hinaichigo = Small Berry
- Suiseiseki = Jade Stone
- Souseiseki = Lapislazuli Stone
- Barasuishou = Rose Crystal
- Kirakishou = Snow Crystal
- Kanaria = Canary Bird

i get most of them are either a trait they have (Hinaichigo is small, Barasuishou attacks with crystals) or their primary color scheme (Kirakishou is white like snow, Kanaria is yellow like the general depiction of a canary).

But I don't understand why Suigintou has the title of Mercury Lamp. From my understanding, Suigintou's color scheme is black (2013 anime) or purple (2004 anime) while Mercury as the metal is silver, while I don't think the planet is black or purple. Nor do I get how Lamp fits.

So how does Suigintou's title match with her?

Comment: [Mercury-vapor lamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-vapor_lamp) are a thing (in Japanese, called _suigintou_, though with different kanji than the Rozen Maiden character). That said, mercury-vapor lamps look blue-green to me, not purple.

Comment: @senshin i did a google search for [Mercury Lamp](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Mercury+Lamp&oq=Mercury+Lamp&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.375j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) and saw them but i didn't know in japan they were called suigintou

Answer (score 1):

I think it refers to the metal mercury (水銀)　which is silver as Suigintou's hair.

It is fragile, it breaks easily (think of thermometer) and when it breaks it is very poisonous. Just like her. She's not bad, just a bit unfortunate and later became evil and poisonous.

It's hard to guess why the kanji for lamp is there though, but during the victorian era, there were lamps with mercury glass reflectors, so it would emit more light