# Is there a significance in the names of the artificial spirits?

Tags: rozen-maiden

Each of the Rozen Maiden Dolls has an artificial spirit. Since there is so much in this series that has a deeper meaning of some sort ([episode titles](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/24295/) and [doll names](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26829/) jump to mind) I’m assuming that their names will also have a deeper meaning — especially since there are names such as *Pizzicato* (Kanaria’s artificial spirit) that are clearly not Japanese at all.

The only one that partially makes sense to me though, is *Berrybell*, Hina-Ichigo’s artificial spirit which fits into the general word-cloud *strawberry*. What significance is behind the names of the other dolls’ artificial spirits?

Answer (score 2):

*This is a community wiki starting point of an answer. Feel free to either contribute to this or append your own answer.*

- Shinku’s artificial spirit is *Hollie*. This could be connected to [*Ilex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holly) (e.g. *Ilex aquifolium),* the prickly plant with the red berries.
- Hina-Ichigo’s artificial spirit is *Berrybell.* Potentially a connection of a ringing bell and a (straw)berry.
- Kanaria’s artificial spirit is *Pizzicato.* This is a [violin playing technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizzicato) also referred to as *plucking* — fitting with the general violin/music theme of Kanaria.
- Souseiseki’s artificial spirit is *Lempicka.* This has the same spelling as the Polish *art deco* painter [Tamara Łempicka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamara_de_Lempicka), although the katakana spelling of the spirit implies a different pronunciation. I don’t know if a connection exists.
- …